# When and why to use buffered input and output streams?

Tags: java

I read that these are used in order to reduce the disk/network call overhead which seems fine in case of write operation. But what is the benefit of doing buffered read?

Comment: To reduce the reading overhead.

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between read and write in this? Each "read" operation causes a system call.

Comment: @Kayaman is correct,.. and writing... excerpt from the javadoc ".. an application can write bytes to the underlying output stream without necessarily causing a call to the underlying system for each byte written."

Comment: @Kayaman - Shouldn't it be reading / writing overhead ? :)

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I have added comment in the first answer. My wrong as I was thinking reading as something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read from a file by byte you make a system call each time and this is expensive operation. With buffered reads you make a system call once per buffer. This code reads 100K from a file on my PC in 130 ms:

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("d:/1");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        is.read();
    }
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

and if I change first line with

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:/1"));
```

it reads 100K in 12 ms.

Comment: Oh, I was not thinking reading in terms of that. So, basically if I have to read  data of 50B and my buffer size is 25B then I can read whole data in just two operations and this underlying operation will be transparent to the client code, right? i.e. my client still read one byte at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from an input stream can sometime be a long operation.

Reading a single byte is not a very good choice if the stream generator save the informations on a bigger chunk. For example a file is saved on the disk in pieces of many kilobytes. If you don't use a buffer you reload from the disk many times the same chunk to read the bytes composing it. Instead using a buffer the read operation save the chunk (or part of it) in the memory reducing the I/O operations on the disk.

Because reading from memory is faster than reading from a disk you can make the same operation gaining a lot of time.

**Note for writing:** the only attention you need to do is to remember that for writing operations the data are not written to the file if you don't flush the buffer at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

When you read bytes from a InputStream, at some level a system call needs to be made to read the physical file from the disk. Now, system calls are costly - they need to pass your parameters from the user space to kernel space and them make a switch to kernel mode before executing. After the call is made the results should again be moved back from kernel to user space.

By using `BufferedInputStream` the number of `read` system calls can be reduced. For example, if you read 1000 bytes in unbuffered mode - you need to make 1000 system calls. Where as in buffered mode, the `BufferedInputStream` reads a block of data (usually 1024 bytes) using single system call. Each of your `read` calls on the input stream - gives the data from its own buffer.