# java.io and file system block size

Tags: java, io, filesystems, java-io

Suppose the file system block size is 4KB, according to my understanding, that means all IO will be at size 4KB. I have 2 questions:

1. When using java.io API, say FileReader, it doesn't read one char each time, instead, it reads 4KB each time into memory. Is it right?
2. If the above is true, then it makes no sense to set buffer size smaller than 4KB when using something like BufferedReader, right? Because at minimum we will fetch 4KB into memory every time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question: No.  It reads the size of the disk block into *kernel memory.*  Java (and programs written in any language) doesn’t have access to that memory.  When you do a raw read, there is no guarantee that the block read by the system remains in memory, or that it remains easily reachable in a way that won’t be expensive to access subsequently.  Here is a possible scenario:

> Program: “I need a byte from this file.”
>   OS: “Loading 4KB block from file.  Here is the byte from that block which you requested.”
>   Program: “Thank you.  I have no more need of that block.”
>   OS: “Okay.  Freeing (or setting aside) the 4KB block since no one needs it anymore.”
>
> …
>
> Program: “My loop needs another byte from this file.”
>   OS: “Loading 4KB block from file.  Here is the byte from that block which you requested.”
>   Program: “Thank you.  I have no more need of that block.”
>   OS: “Okay.  Freeing (or setting aside) the 4KB block since no one needs it anymore.”
>
> etc.

Of course, I have greatly oversimplified things.  The OS is likely to cache the block it has read.  But you have no way of knowing for how long.  Maybe milliseconds, maybe many minutes, maybe not at all.

This isn’t just a consideration in Java.  C has had separate [read(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [fread(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) functions for a long time.

See also: [When and why to use buffered input and output streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326424/when-and-why-to-use-buffered-input-and-output-streams)

Comment: Thank you. So raw FileReader does read file one char each time, only that it reads from kernel memory instead of disk, right? Suppose I need to read the first 5 chars from the file, FileReader has to ask kernel memory 5 times, while kernel memory may need to load the very same block several times (5 times in the worst case), so a buffer with size of 5 bytes (suppose ASCII) still helps in this case? Because now FileReader only need to ask kernel memory 1 time, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The same effect can also be achieved by calling FileReader’s inherited methods which take a `char[]` or `CharBuffer` as an argument.

Comment: Don’t mix up `FileReader` and `FileInputStream`. They sound similar but are entirely different. The `FileReader` extends `InputStreamReader` and will pass a `FileInputStream` to the super constructor. The `InputStreamReader` uses a decoder for converting the bytes to chars, which will by default use a buffer of 8192 bytes. So asking a `FileReader` for a single character five times in a row will not lead to multiple OS read calls. That doesn’t mean that it’s cheap. There’s synchronization, validity checks, and in the reference implementation, a new `char[2]` array will be created for each read.

Comment: @Holger I did see code line DEFAULT_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192 after checking the source, thank you for pointing it out.  What about FileInputStream, does the raw FileInputStream fetch one byte each time from kernel memory?

Comment: @gfytd yes, when you invoke read methods on a `FileInputStream` directly, every invocation will end up in a system call.